# Is it any automatic tool / generator/ automatic task runner for writing android xml layouts with simpler syntax?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am frontend developer, and start learning Android development.

I was really shocked to this crazy many-chars syntax for writing UIs.

```
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
```

In web frontend there are some tools like SASS, LESS, Typescript, which allow to write css/js much faster with some syntax sugar, while the real code generates automatically.

Is it any tool for android layouts, that will convert something like this:

```
CodeFont {
  layout_width: fill_parent
  layout_height: wrap_content
  color: #000ff00;
  typeface: monospace
}
```

Into the code above?

Same thing is

```
  <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
```

to this

```
<textView id="@+id/text" style="CodeFont">Lalala</text>
```

Why do i need to write this android:blabla word all the time???

Answer (score 1):

take a look at: https://nativecss.com/

However, I dont think that you can transform like in the second example you gave since you loose information (layout_width and layout_height are only given implicit and this can hardly be done by a transpiler)